# laravel/homestead installation error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, homestead

I am relatively new to using `laravel/homestead` and I'm having issues with the install. I have `composer` in my PATH and I'm trying to use the `homestead init` command and I am recieving this error?

Any advice would be appreciated.

```
goldenos@GoldenOS:~$ homestead init
/home/goldenos/Homestead/scripts/homestead.rb:4:in `configure': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
from /home/goldenos/Homestead/Vagrantfile:28:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/config/v2/loader.rb:37:in `call'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/config/v2/loader.rb:37:in `load'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/config/loader.rb:103:in `block (2 levels) in load'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/config/loader.rb:97:in `each'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/config/loader.rb:97:in `block in load'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/config/loader.rb:94:in `each'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/config/loader.rb:94:in `load'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/vagrantfile.rb:28:in `initialize'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/environment.rb:655:in `new'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/environment.rb:655:in `vagrantfile'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/environment.rb:407:in `host'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/environment.rb:178:in `block in action_runner'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/action/runner.rb:33:in `call'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/action/runner.rb:33:in `run'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/environment.rb:394:in `hook'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/environment.rb:637:in `unload'
from /usr/bin/vagrant:176:in `ensure in <main>'
from /usr/bin/vagrant:176:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34374481/configure-undefined-method-while-i-vagrant-up-my-vm

Comment: I highly recommend not to use homestead...homestead is so complicated for beginners to configure it. Instead install yourself a virtual machine with ubuntu 32bit (low space usage) there is a nice tutorial on youtube under name (Install Laravel 5.2 on Ubuntu 16.04) your host machine will be clean and if you mess up something just delete it and start again!

Comment: The answer for that particular question didn't help me, any other assistance would be greatly appreciated! -Luke

Comment: I had laravel/homestead installed previously but had help from someone that was experienced and was just becoming familiar using it when I had had a system error and ended up having to start over. I will look into the virtual machine thanks for the assistance!